# Why using NOT IN syntax in mysql is causing DB server crash?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have two mysql tables one having these fields

Table name - `residential`:

```
ListingID varchar(12),
ListingStatus varchar(15)
```

with primary key on `ListingID` and an index on `ListingStatus`.

Another table - `mlscheck`:

```
mls varchar(12), 
status varchar(15)
```

with same primary key on mls and indes on status.

When I try to do anything like:

```
delete from residential 
where ListingStatus = "Active" and 
ListingID NOT IN(select mls from mlscheck where status = "Active")
```

even a:

```
delete from residential 
where ListingStatus = "Active" 
    and LIstingID NOT IN(select mls from mlscheck)
```

neither works, both crash my database and I have to restart.

Should I be learning how to use joins, union , etc, ?   I thought NOT IN was a decent command.   Can I get some input from some of you experts ?

Comment: How many record are there in your tables?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes (ex. 'Active')? Also, as a general rule, do not index columns unless they are 95% unique. The optimizer will ignore the index and it will incur unnecessary overhead.

Comment: 1. Even if it is vry heavy it should not crash, THIS IS DB. 2. Maybe you have other memory/disk space problems, check it, 3. BASIC OF BASICS did you check the mysql log?

Answer (score 0):

In performance, joins are always better or equals than subqueries

this query is heavy for the server, wich must select all row on `mls`, and this for each row in `residential`

That why the database crash.

By Using joins:

```
DELETE r FROM residential r
LEFT JOIN mlscheck
    ON mls = ListingID
WHERE ListingStatus = "Active"
    AND mls IS NULL
```

Only `residential` rows are deleted. (that the `r`) when no `mls` row corresponding are found.

Comment: Dang!  you guys are so fast, I can;'t

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that about 350 fields in tbe residential table   170,000 rows         rowlength  3,209   and rowsize  3268           the mlscheck table has only 2 fields, total rows, 43,000 or so . and I taking the indexes off of the ones that are not 95% unique

Answer (score 0):

The NOT IN operator can be expensive for table with large records. Judging by your table name you are trying to do something with the MLS listings which is a large data set.

What you can do is to write a script that does the deletion chunk by chunk:

> delete from residential  where ListingStatus = "Active" and  ListingID
>   NOT IN(select mls from mlscheck where status = "Active" LIMIT 0, 100)
>
> delete from residential  where ListingStatus = "Active" and  ListingID
>   where ListingStatus = "Active" and  ListingID NOT IN(select mls from
>   mlscheck where status = "Active" LIMIT 101, 200)
>
> delete from residential  where ListingStatus = "Active" and  ListingID
>   where ListingStatus = "Active" and  ListingID NOT IN(select mls from
>   mlscheck where status = "Active" LIMIT 201, 300)
>
> etc..

That is if you don't want to use the JOIN way mentioned by BAK.

Comment: yeah , there are only about 114,000 records in the residential table  but there are like 350 fields .   I did not know that about the index being overlooked if not unique, thanks .can I get a join example?  may as well step up to the big boys

Comment: hey guys, I feel kinda dumb,  I noticed that the newly created table mlscheck, was created with a character set of swedish latin somethiing or other and all my other tables are character set utf8 ,  now everything works great.   but I did learn about overhead, and I appreciate  the join I will save for next time.   Thanks guys